# Is it possible to have multiple values per Node?

Tags: java, linked-list

So far I have learned that linked list is a Node pointing to the next

first - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 -6 - 7-null

My question is, is it possible to divide the list into equal chunks like below

first - |1 2 3| - |4 5 6| - |7| - null

I already tried packaging the data into Objects like below

```
   class IntegerData
    {
      private int[] data;
      private int numData;

      public IntegerData(int[] data)
      {
        data = new int[numData];
        numData = 8;
      }
    }

This is my Node class.
class Node
{
  private int m;
  private Node next;
  private Node prev;

  public Node(Node prev,IntegerData data,Node next)
  {
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
  }

  public Node getNext()
  {
    return next;
  }
  public void setNext(Node next)
  {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public Node getPrev()
  {
    return prev;
  }

  public void setPrev(Node next)
  {
    this.prev = next;
  } 
}
```

I am stuck as of now. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Well, you should assign `numData` **before** you use its value to create an array. Other than that, perhaps it will help if you explain *why* you want to chunk your linked list.

Comment: 'I already tried packaging the data into Objects like below' - Sounds like a valid solution... Why is this not working?

Comment: Pointers takes up too much memory. The idea behind this is to use less pointers and Nodes

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a list of lists

```
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(4,5,6);
    List<Integer> list3 = Arrays.asList(7);
    List<List<Integer>> masterList = Arrays.asList(list1, list2, list3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally your Node should be like this:

```
public class Node<T> {

private Node<T> prev;
private Node<T> next;
private T data;

public Node(Node<T> prev, T data) {
    this.prev = prev;
    this.data = data;
    if (prev != null) {
        prev.setNext(this);
    }
}

private void setNext(Node<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public Node<T> getPrev() {
    return prev;
}

public Node<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}

public T getData() {
    return data;
}
}
```

Now you can put anything inside your list, for example an array of Integer:

```
 Node<Integer[]> n1 = new Node<Integer[]>(null, new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
 Node<Integer[]> n2 = new Node<Integer[]>(n1, new Integer[]{4, 5, 6});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible that Each node have multiple values.
For this You have to change the structure of node.
You are using this one

```
  private int m;
  private Node next;
  private Node prev;
```

You have to create more variable or even a array (according to your choice)
In This Case I get that you need three variables in one node so just create three like this

```
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int z;
   private Node next;
   private Node prev;
```